# Figuring out what this sed command do

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, systemctl

I'm having a hard time trying to discover what the next comand is doing.

I'm trying to monitor different services on Linux using systemctl. I need a Json output with all the services on Linux that are running on the machine.

The problem is that with this comand the Status ouput is: "enable   enabled". I only need the first parameter (state), and trying to delete the second one (Vendor preset) I really don't get it working. Basically because I don't understand it. I know with Sed is trying to replace some strings but with so many characters for me this isn't readable.

```
echo "{\"data\":[$(systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep \.service|grep -v "@"|sed -E -e "s/\.service\s+/\",\"{#STATUS}\":\"/;s/(\s+)?$/\"},/;s/^/{\"{#NAME}\":\"/;$ s/.$//")]}"
```

**Result:**

```
    "data": [{
            "{#NAME}": "accounts-daemon",
            "{#STATUS}": "enabled         enabled"
        },
        {
            "{#NAME}": "acpid",
            "{#STATUS}": "disabled        enabled"
        }, {
            "{#NAME}": "zabbix-agent",
            "{#STATUS}": "enabled         enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
    "data": [{
            "{#NAME}": "accounts-daemon",
            "{#STATUS}": "enabled"
        },
        {
            "{#NAME}": "acpid",
            "{#STATUS}": "disabled"
        }, {
            "{#NAME}": "zabbix-agent",
            "{#STATUS}": "enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Command without "sed":** systemctl list-unit-files --type=service

| UNIT FILE | STATE | VENDOR PRESET |
| --- | --- | --- |
| accounts-daemon.service | enabled | enabled |
| acpid.service | disabled | enabled |
| zabbix-agent | static | enabled |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant substitute in your code is

```
s/(\s+)?$/
```

Try to replace that by deleting everyting starting with the first seperator (\s)

That is

```
s/\s.*$/
```

The modified command becomes

```
echo "{\"data\":[$(systemctl list-unit-files --type=service|grep \.service|grep -v "@"|sed -E -e "s/\.service\s+/\",\"{#STATUS}\":\"/;s/\s.*$/\"},/;s/^/{\"{#NAME}\":\"/;$ s/.$//")]}"
```